# jquery create a new object and insert html text

Tags: jquery

i create new div, and how insert text(html text) in this new div?

```
var div_obj = $(document.createElement("div")).attr({'class': 'test'}).css({'width' : size, 'height' : height, 'background' : bg});
```

I try:

```
div_obj.innerHTML = "text";
```

But don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) here,  like this:

```
div_obj.html("text");
```

[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) is a DOM element property (not a jQuery object one), to access it you'd need to get the raw `<div>` DOM element, like this:

```
div_obj[0].innerHTML = "text";
```

---

As an aside: in jQuery 1.4+ there's a shorthand for creation, [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), like this:

```
$("<div/>", { 'class': 'test', 
               css: {'width' : size, 'height' : height, 'background' : bg}, 
               html: 'text' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you're mixing the native DOM method calls with jQuery methods. Try this:

```
$('<div>').addClass('test').css({'width': size, 'height': height, 'background': bg}).html('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').html('html text');
```

but you should really give the div an id so it can be referenced by jquery without altering the content of other divs